# Wildfly - RestEasy, JAX-RS : limit request per second for user/ip

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I've some simple jax-rs web-services as EJB for an e-commerce.
I'm using Wildfly 9 and restEasy.

I want to serve my data to a lot of users, but i want to limit the request/seconds that a user can do.

I want to prevent some DoS attack or scraping system : an user(bot) could read all the products each second and the other users will wait.

Is there some system to block request per user per second? For example "at least 10 request/second per user".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bozho has implemented a simple one and discusses the pros and cons [here](https://techblog.bozho.net/basic-api-rate-limiting/).

This article also mentions Guava's [`RateLimiter`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html).

The last update of the blog entry also mentions [bucket4j](https://github.com/vladimir-bukhtoyarov/bucket4j).

Comment: Nice hint.
The implementation in the link was sufficient.